# Semaphore.OpenExisting delay on x86 if semaphore does not exist

Tags: c#, x86

When I build and run the following with target=x86, there is a 6-7 seconds delay before the exception is thrown. When building for x64 or Any CPU, there is no delay.

Is there anything I can do to remove the delay on x86?

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Semaphore mySem;
        Console.WriteLine("Before OpenExisting");
        mySem = Semaphore.OpenExisting("Global\\MyGlobalNonexistingSem");
        mySem.Release();
        Console.WriteLine("After OpenExisting");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ex: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the debugger show the thread is doing during this delay?

Comment: FWIW, I can't reproduce this using VS2017 and .NET 4.7 on my Windows 10 machine.